# h2o Actual column must contain binary labels

Tags: r, h2o

I keep on getting the following error in version:3.8.0.3 when trying to predict on a frame either in R or on the website.

I get this error even if I try to run a subset of the training set.

> Error evaluating cell
>
> Error calling POST
>   /3/Predictions/models/DeepLearning_model_R_14596238744_1/frames/t2
>   with opts {"predictions_frame":"prediction-b0eb96...
>
> ERROR MESSAGE: Actual column must contain binary class labels, but
>   found cardinality 1!

Even getting this error when I use a subset of the data frame I used to train the model:

```
t2 <- training_set[1:5,]
```

Comment: A part of your dataset might be useful. As it stands it is difficult to see where the problem might be. check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me while including the (true/oracle) classification label to the feature data frame used in the predict function.
Anecdotally, this specific data.frame was entirely composed of observations from one class.

Two suggestions :

- Try to remove the label/target column from your frame
- or ensure that all the classes are represented